# Duplicate key error handling and unhandled promise rejection with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, error-handling, promise

I have a user schema which follows the given schema.
According to the purpose I let the user signup for the site and later allow them to update their cars and their car numbers. 
The car plate number must be a unique string while the name could be anything.

Here is my Schema ->

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
require('mongoose-type-email')

const Email = mongoose.Types.Email;
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var carNum = new Schema ({
    plateNum : {

        type : String,
        unique : true,
        sparse: true

    },
    name : {
        type : String
    },
    price : {
        type : Number
    }
});

var userSchema = new Schema({
    name : {
        type : String,
        required : true
    },
    email : {
        type : Email,
        required : true,
        unique : true
    },
    password : {
        type : String,
        required : true
    },
    car : [carNum]
});




var users = mongoose.model('user',userSchema);

module.exports = users;
```

Here is the code that handles the insertion.

```
.post((req,res,next) =>{
    var plate = req.body.plateNum;
    var carname = req.body.carName;
    users.findOne({'_id': `${userId}`})
    .then((result) =>{
        res.statusCode = 200;
        res.setHeader('Content-type',"application/json");
        res.json(result)

        result.car.push({
            plateNum : plate,
            name : carname,
        })
        result.save()

    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log( "Error :    "+ err);
        res.send('The name plate number already exists')
    });  
})
```

When i try to send a duplicate or already existing name plate it returns unhandled promise rejection warning with mongoDB error.

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: tarp.users index: car.plateNum_1 dup key: { car.plateNum: "asd" }
    at Function.create (C:\Users\Harsh Verma\Documents\VIT\TARP\Project\Tarp Project\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\error.js:44:12)
    at toError (C:\Users\Harsh Verma\Documents\VIT\TARP\Project\Tarp Project\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:150:22)
    at coll.s.topology.update (C:\Users\Harsh Verma\Documents\VIT\TARP\Project\Tarp Project\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\common_functions.js:373:39)    
    at handler (C:\Users\Harsh Verma\Documents\VIT\TARP\Project\Tarp Project\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\sdam\topology.js:1000:24)
    at wireProtocol.(anonymous function) (C:\Users\Harsh Verma\Documents\VIT\TARP\Project\Tarp Project\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\sdam\server.js:457:5)     
    at C:\Users\Harsh Verma\Documents\VIT\TARP\Project\Tarp Project\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\pool.js:408:18
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
(node:14348) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch().
```

I do have `.catch` placed there so is there something missing there.

I want to let the user know that the plate already exists.

However I did manage to get this working but I do not know why this is working not the first thing.

Here is the working thing

```
.post((req,res,next) =>{
    var plate = req.body.plateNum;
    var carname = req.body.carName;
    users.findOne({'_id': `${userId}`})
    .then((result) =>{
        res.statusCode = 200;
        res.setHeader('Content-type',"application/json");
        // res.send(result);
        result.car.push({
            plateNum : plate,
            name : carname,
        })

        result.save()
        .then((saved) => {
           // Nothing gets consoled
            console.log(saved)
        })
        .catch((err) => {

            console.log( "Error :    "+ err);
            res.send('The name already exists')
        });
    })
    .catch((err) => res.send('Unable to save : ' + err));  
})
```

Comment: Any help is appreciated and if you need anything please let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First one is not working because the `Duplicate` exception is thrown by `.save()` not by `.findOne()` and once you add `catch` block to the `save()` it works.

Comment: So what i have done is in the second code is the correct way to handle it?

PS : Thank you very much for answering.

Comment: Yes because every operation on database needs to handle the errors and exceptions on its own, 1 operation for example `findOne()` cannot catch exceptions from another operation like `save()`. P.S- You can mark it correct if it solved your issue. Cheers!